# Newly associated account does show up elsewhere

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, user-accounts

I created an account on android.SE.  Okay, last night.  Guess my expectation (experience?) that this showed up on the [main site](https://stackexchange.com/users/e2556160-2dc7-493b-b285-9888b743b8f2?tab=accounts) is wrong.  But all my other accounts show up in android.SE's accounts tab.

So, when does this info get synced?  Is there a list of these times somewhere?  If not, could we get one?  Would make things less mysterious/baffling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had a data sync issue.  I've fixed you up.

Answer (score 0):

I have created [my account on android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/4765/kiamlaluno) today, voted 30 questions, and my account is showing in [my general profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4347a38f-4f69-4816-978a-b7fd19124480?tab=accounts).
If you just registered an account, but you didn't do any activity on that site, or gained
badges (which means you didn't do any relevant activity), that could explain why your android.SE account doesn't appear in your global profile.

Comment: Strange... I did two upvotes (did those before you answered), and two badges (started with Autobiographer, due to complete profile).  Still doesn't show up.  And I'm pretty sure other accounts showed up w/o activity from me.  This does smack of a bug.